# COVID restrictions in a class: how to space kids efficiently with minimal distance apart?

Tags: geometry, voronoi-diagram

At my kid's school, existing COVID regulations mandate a minimal distance of 1.5m between each child (excluding on the wall sides). This causes the classroom to not have sufficient space at the moment leading to a spillover in an adjacent class. Is simply placing kids in rows/columns the most efficient shape to pack as many children as possible in the room while respecting distance or is there a more optimal layout? Reworded: in a n x m rectangle, how many points are able to fit if each point is constrained to be at least d meters apart?

Comment: If you imagine the circle of radius d around each child, this question can be reframed as a [circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) problem; a hexagonal arrangement would be the most optimal.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. So if understood correctly, the question becomes: how many hexagons fit a rectangle given the distance between each hex center is d meters apart, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  To clarify, however, while a hexagonal (honeycomb) tiling is the densest possible for an open space, there may be special cases near the walls of the room, or when d is large with respect to the size of the room. For examples, it may be worth looking at the [most optimal circle packings for square rooms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square) as well.

Comment: Thanks @flatan - you have helped resolve an annoying logistics issue